# Cannot connect to Mongodb cluster via Mongodb shell

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell, mongodb-cluster

I've been trying to connect to the Mongodb Atlas cluster via terminal using shell but something funny is happening and it always throws me these logs:

```
MongoDB shell version v4.2.0
Enter password:
connecting to: mongodb://cluster0-shard-00-00-m0uql.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-m0uql.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-m0uql.mongodb.net:27017/test?authSource=admin&compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&ssl=true
2019-12-08T12:32:06.915+0000 I  NETWORK  [js] Starting new replica set monitor for Cluster0-shard-0/cluster0-shard-00-00-m0uql.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-m0uql.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-m0uql.mongodb.net:27017
2019-12-08T12:32:06.916+0000 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to cluster0-shard-00-01-m0uql.mongodb.net:27017
2019-12-08T12:32:06.916+0000 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to cluster0-shard-00-02-m0uql.mongodb.net:27017
2019-12-08T12:32:06.916+0000 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to cluster0-shard-00-00-m0uql.mongodb.net:27017
2019-12-08T12:32:07.098+0000 W  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Unable to reach primary for set Cluster0-shard-0
2019-12-08T12:32:07.098+0000 I  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Cannot reach any nodes for set Cluster0-shard-0. Please check network connectivity and the status of the set. This has happened for 1 checks in a row.
2019-12-08T12:32:07.534+0000 W  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Unable to reach primary for set Cluster0-shard-0
2019-12-08T12:32:07.534+0000 I  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Cannot reach any nodes for set Cluster0-shard-0. Please check network connectivity and the status of the set. This has happened for 2 checks in a row.
2019-12-08T12:32:07.917+0000 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to cluster0-shard-00-00-m0uql.mongodb.net:27017
2019-12-08T12:32:07.917+0000 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to cluster0-shard-00-02-m0uql.mongodb.net:27017
2019-12-08T12:32:07.917+0000 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to cluster0-shard-00-01-m0uql.mongodb.net:27017
2019-12-08T12:32:08.032+0000 W  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Unable to reach primary for set Cluster0-shard-0
2019-12-08T12:32:08.032+0000 I  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Cannot reach any nodes for set Cluster0-shard-0. Please check network connectivity and the status of the set. This has happened for 3 checks in a row.
2019-12-08T12:32:08.539+0000 W  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Unable to reach primary for set Cluster0-shard-0
2019-12-08T12:32:08.539+0000 I  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Cannot reach any nodes for set Cluster0-shard-0. Please check network connectivity and the status of the set. This has happened for 4 checks in a row.
2019-12-08T12:32:09.038+0000 W  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Unable to reach primary for set Cluster0-shard-0
2019-12-08T12:32:09.039+0000 I  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Cannot reach any nodes for set Cluster0-shard-0. Please check network connectivity and the status of the set. This has happened for 5 checks in a row.
2019-12-08T12:32:09.425+0000 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to cluster0-shard-00-01-m0uql.mongodb.net:27017
2019-12-08T12:32:09.426+0000 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to cluster0-shard-00-02-m0uql.mongodb.net:27017
2019-12-08T12:32:09.426+0000 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to cluster0-shard-00-00-m0uql.mongodb.net:27017
2019-12-08T12:32:09.543+0000 W  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Unable to reach primary for set Cluster0-shard-0
2019-12-08T12:32:09.543+0000 I  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Cannot reach any nodes for set Cluster0-shard-0. Please check network connectivity and the status of the set. This has happened for 6 checks in a row.
2019-12-08T12:32:10.035+0000 W  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Unable to reach primary for set Cluster0-shard-0
2019-12-08T12:32:10.035+0000 I  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Cannot reach any nodes for set Cluster0-shard-0. Please check network connectivity and the status of the set. This has happened for 7 checks in a row.
2019-12-08T12:32:10.430+0000 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to cluster0-shard-00-02-m0uql.mongodb.net:27017
2019-12-08T12:32:10.430+0000 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to cluster0-shard-00-01-m0uql.mongodb.net:27017
2019-12-08T12:32:10.431+0000 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to cluster0-shard-00-00-m0uql.mongodb.net:27017
2019-12-08T12:32:10.546+0000 W  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Unable to reach primary for set Cluster0-shard-0
2019-12-08T12:32:10.546+0000 I  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Cannot reach any nodes for set Cluster0-shard-0. Please check network connectivity and the status of the set. This has happened for 8 checks in a row.
2019-12-08T12:32:11.036+0000 W  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Unable to reach primary for set Cluster0-shard-0
2019-12-08T12:32:11.036+0000 I  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Cannot reach any nodes for set Cluster0-shard-0. Please check network connectivity and the status of the set. This has happened for 9 checks in a row.
2019-12-08T12:32:11.433+0000 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to cluster0-shard-00-01-m0uql.mongodb.net:27017
2019-12-08T12:32:11.433+0000 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to cluster0-shard-00-02-m0uql.mongodb.net:27017
2019-12-08T12:32:11.433+0000 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to cluster0-shard-00-00-m0uql.mongodb.net:27017
2019-12-08T12:32:11.549+0000 W  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Unable to reach primary for set Cluster0-shard-0
2019-12-08T12:32:11.549+0000 I  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Cannot reach any nodes for set Cluster0-shard-0. Please check network connectivity and the status of the set. This has happened for 10 checks in a row.
2019-12-08T12:32:12.046+0000 W  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Unable to reach primary for set Cluster0-shard-0
2019-12-08T12:32:12.046+0000 I  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Cannot reach any nodes for set Cluster0-shard-0. Please check network connectivity and the status of the set. This has happened for 11 checks in a row.
2019-12-08T12:32:12.435+0000 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to cluster0-shard-00-00-m0uql.mongodb.net:27017
2019-12-08T12:32:12.435+0000 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to cluster0-shard-00-01-m0uql.mongodb.net:27017
2019-12-08T12:32:12.435+0000 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to cluster0-shard-00-02-m0uql.mongodb.net:27017
2019-12-08T12:32:12.551+0000 W  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Unable to reach primary for set Cluster0-shard-0
2019-12-08T12:32:13.048+0000 W  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Unable to reach primary for set Cluster0-shard-0
2019-12-08T12:32:13.568+0000 W  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Unable to reach primary for set Cluster0-shard-0
2019-12-08T12:32:13.928+0000 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to cluster0-shard-00-01-m0uql.mongodb.net:27017
2019-12-08T12:32:13.928+0000 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to cluster0-shard-00-00-m0uql.mongodb.net:27017
2019-12-08T12:32:13.928+0000 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to cluster0-shard-00-02-m0uql.mongodb.net:27017
2019-12-08T12:32:14.049+0000 W  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Unable to reach primary for set Cluster0-shard-0
2019-12-08T12:32:14.555+0000 W  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Unable to reach primary for set Cluster0-shard-0
2019-12-08T12:32:14.930+0000 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to cluster0-shard-00-01-m0uql.mongodb.net:27017
2019-12-08T12:32:14.930+0000 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to cluster0-shard-00-02-m0uql.mongodb.net:27017
2019-12-08T12:32:14.931+0000 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to cluster0-shard-00-00-m0uql.mongodb.net:27017
2019-12-08T12:32:15.051+0000 W  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Unable to reach primary for set Cluster0-shard-0
2019-12-08T12:32:15.556+0000 W  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Unable to reach primary for set Cluster0-shard-0
2019-12-08T12:32:15.934+0000 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to cluster0-shard-00-01-m0uql.mongodb.net:27017
2019-12-08T12:32:15.934+0000 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to cluster0-shard-00-00-m0uql.mongodb.net:27017
2019-12-08T12:32:15.934+0000 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to cluster0-shard-00-02-m0uql.mongodb.net:27017
2019-12-08T12:32:16.053+0000 W  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Unable to reach primary for set Cluster0-shard-0
2019-12-08T12:32:16.561+0000 W  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Unable to reach primary for set Cluster0-shard-0
2019-12-08T12:32:16.935+0000 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to cluster0-shard-00-01-m0uql.mongodb.net:27017
2019-12-08T12:32:16.936+0000 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to cluster0-shard-00-02-m0uql.mongodb.net:27017
2019-12-08T12:32:16.936+0000 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to cluster0-shard-00-00-m0uql.mongodb.net:27017
2019-12-08T12:32:17.052+0000 W  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Unable to reach primary for set Cluster0-shard-0
2019-12-08T12:32:17.052+0000 I  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Cannot reach any nodes for set Cluster0-shard-0. Please check network connectivity and the status of the set. This has happened for 21 checks in a row.
2019-12-08T12:32:17.562+0000 W  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Unable to reach primary for set Cluster0-shard-0
2019-12-08T12:32:17.936+0000 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to cluster0-shard-00-01-m0uql.mongodb.net:27017
2019-12-08T12:32:18.054+0000 W  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Unable to reach primary for set Cluster0-shard-0
2019-12-08T12:32:18.449+0000 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to cluster0-shard-00-00-m0uql.mongodb.net:27017
2019-12-08T12:32:18.449+0000 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to cluster0-shard-00-02-m0uql.mongodb.net:27017
2019-12-08T12:32:18.564+0000 W  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Unable to reach primary for set Cluster0-shard-0
2019-12-08T12:32:18.938+0000 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to cluster0-shard-00-01-m0uql.mongodb.net:27017
2019-12-08T12:32:19.060+0000 W  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Unable to reach primary for set Cluster0-shard-0
2019-12-08T12:32:19.453+0000 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to cluster0-shard-00-02-m0uql.mongodb.net:27017
2019-12-08T12:32:19.453+0000 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to cluster0-shard-00-00-m0uql.mongodb.net:27017
2019-12-08T12:32:19.575+0000 W  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Unable to reach primary for set Cluster0-shard-0
2019-12-08T12:32:19.941+0000 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to cluster0-shard-00-01-m0uql.mongodb.net:27017
2019-12-08T12:32:20.060+0000 W  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Unable to reach primary for set Cluster0-shard-0
2019-12-08T12:32:20.570+0000 W  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Unable to reach primary for set Cluster0-shard-0
2019-12-08T12:32:20.941+0000 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to cluster0-shard-00-02-m0uql.mongodb.net:27017
2019-12-08T12:32:20.941+0000 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to cluster0-shard-00-00-m0uql.mongodb.net:27017
2019-12-08T12:32:21.066+0000 W  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Unable to reach primary for set Cluster0-shard-0
2019-12-08T12:32:21.453+0000 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to cluster0-shard-00-01-m0uql.mongodb.net:27017
2019-12-08T12:32:21.574+0000 W  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Unable to reach primary for set Cluster0-shard-0
2019-12-08T12:32:21.945+0000 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to cluster0-shard-00-00-m0uql.mongodb.net:27017
2019-12-08T12:32:21.946+0000 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to cluster0-shard-00-02-m0uql.mongodb.net:27017
2019-12-08T12:32:22.062+0000 W  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Unable to reach primary for set Cluster0-shard-0
2019-12-08T12:32:22.062+0000 I  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Cannot reach any nodes for set Cluster0-shard-0. Please check network connectivity and the status of the set. This has happened for 31 checks in a row.


*** It looks like this is a MongoDB Atlas cluster. Please ensure that your IP whitelist allows connections from your network.


2019-12-08T12:32:22.063+0000 E  QUERY    [js] Error: connect failed to replica set Cluster0-shard-0/cluster0-shard-00-00-m0uql.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-m0uql.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-m0uql.mongodb.net:27017 :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:341:17
@(connect):2:6
2019-12-08T12:32:22.065+0000 F  -        [main] exception: connect failed
2019-12-08T12:32:22.066+0000 E  -        [main] exiting with code 1
```

So, to be clear, my IP address is in the list, so it shouldn't be a problem.

What I noticed is that my Atlas cluster's version is 4.0.13 and I downloaded the same version of mongodb-community. However, whenever I try to install the shell, it only gives my 4.2 version (you can see it in the logs). It's my personal assumption that the version incompatibility is an issue, but maybe someone knows a different reason?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks everyone, I found out what was wrong. On my working laptop, the IP is different than to what it was showing me in the terminal and network preferences. I found it via Activity section where it logged my local activities.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me, but I realized that I had my VPN on. You can configure your database to allow other IPs, obviously, or just disconnect from your VPN.